# RUBY pdf-extract gem to extract references from scholarly article does not work?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pdf-extraction

I am a newbie on both ruby and its pdf-extract gem. After installing ruby for 64-bit and installing related Development Kit, I have installed pdf-extract with the code below:

> gem install pdf-extract

By checking the quick examples from the web site https://github.com/CrossRef/pdfextract,

I have tried

> pdf-extract extract --references C:/dnm1.pdf

When executing the code above, I get errors like below:

> C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:
>   384:in `block in require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::
>   CommandError)
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.0/lib/command
>   er/runner.rb:383:in`each'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.0/lib/command
>   er/runner.rb:383:in `require_program'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.0/lib/command
>   er/runner.rb:51:in`run!'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.0/lib/command
>   er/delegates.rb:8:in `run!'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.0/lib/command
>   er/import.rb:10:in`block in '
>   C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require
>   ': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gem
>   s/2.0.0/gems/libsvm-ruby-swig-0.4.0/ext/libsvm.so (LoadError)
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
>   5:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libsvm-ruby-swig-0.4.0/lib/
>   svm.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
>   5:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
>   5:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pdf-extract-0.1.1/lib/refer
>   ences/score.rb:1:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pdf-extract-0.1.1/lib/refer
>   ences/references.rb:3:in `require_relative'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pdf-extract-0.1.1/lib/refer
>   ences/references.rb:3:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pdf-extract-0.1.1/lib/pdf-e
>   xtract.rb:10:in `require_relative'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pdf-extract-0.1.1/lib/pdf-e
>   xtract.rb:10:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pdf-extract-0.1.1/bin/pdf-e
>   xtract:5:in `require_relative'
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pdf-extract-0.1.1/bin/pdf-e
>   xtract:5:in`'
>
> from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/pdf-extract:23:in load
>           from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/pdf-extract:23:in main

I have checked pdf-extract related problems through the web but could not find much helpful stuff. What am I doing wrong?